# how does . operator behave in python 2.x?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using python 2.7.
I came across an amazing thing while using it.
Whenever I try -3.-4 it gives -7 OR 3.-4 it gives -1
but at same time when i use -3.4 it gives -3.4.
why so?

Comment: That's not an operator, that's a decimal point.

Comment: Just curious, what did you expect -3.-4 to do? Was it multiplication?

Comment: Can we have a "Question of the Day" on Stack Overflow?  Please.

Answer (score 2):

It treats the expression

```
-3.-4
```

as

```
(-3.) - (4)
```

which means

```
(-3.0) - (4)
```

That is why the result is `-7.0`. But when you do `-3.4`, it will be treated as the floating point number `-3.4` itself.

Answer (score 2):

It is called [Maximal munch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_munch). The tokenizer eats as much as possible of the string to construct the number. So the expression:

```
-3.-4
```

is munched by the tokenizer as:

```
{-} {3.} {-} {4}
```

Evaluating the expression gives you the answer -7.

Comment: Thank you everybody for making this concept clear to me. Thanx again..!!